# "Неясен" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> ... их статус совершенно неясен.

"Неясен" - не слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Не* пишется слитно в данном случае. **Их статус совершенно неясен.** По-моему, раздельное написание будет ошибкой.

> [Слитно](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-00000000d8573f987cea4c65181925c6)....Если прилагательное или причастие употребляется со словами, обозначающими степень качества: очень, весьма, крайне, почти, **совершенно**, чрезвычайно, совсем (в значении очень). Все эти слова могут употребляться и с прилагательными без не (очень умный).
>
> Примеры: крайне непродуманное решение, очень некрасивый поступок, **совершенно** нелогичный ответ, совсем незначительная сумма

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта допустимы. Отрицаете положительный признак (ясность) - пишите раздельно, утверждаете отрицательный (неясность) - слитно.

Comment: Если "совершенно" поясняет, дополняет неясность, то может быть поэтому раздельно?

Comment: "Совершенно туманен, загадочен" - вот вам примерные синонимы без НЕ. Поэтому слитное написание - не ошибка. Впрочем, как и раздельное